# how to get the same output of voronoin of MATLAB by scipy.spatial.Voronoi of Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, voronoi

I use `voronoin` of MATLAB to judge the connection between cells, and I want to convert this function to Python.

When I use `scipy.spatial.Voronoi` of Python, the output is a little different.
For example, I used the same input for MATLAB and Python as you can see in the next code.

MATLAB:

```
seed = [ 17.746    -0.37283   -0.75523;
         6.1704     1.3404     7.0341;
        -7.7211     5.4282     4.5016;
         5.8014     2.1252    -6.2491;
       -16.047     -2.8472    -0.024795;
        -2.2967    -6.7334     0.60707]
[vvern_mat, vceln_mat] = voronoin(seed);
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
seed = np.array([[ 17.746   ,  -0.37283 ,  -0.75523 ],
       [  6.1704  ,   1.3404  ,   7.0341  ],
       [ -7.7211  ,   5.4282  ,   4.5016  ],
       [  5.8014  ,   2.1252  ,  -6.2491  ],
       [-16.047   ,  -2.8472  ,  -0.024795],
       [ -2.2967  ,  -6.7334  ,   0.60707 ]])
vor = Voronoi(seed)
vvern_py = vor.vertices
vceln_py = vor.regions
```

The output is as follows:

MATLAB:

```
vvern_mat = 
        Inf       Inf       Inf
        -6.9386    1.7980   -7.7861
        -15.9902  -20.8031   50.1840
        29.5016  106.3690    5.9214
        8.6816   -6.5899   -0.1741
        -0.2027    2.1210    0.5874

vceln_mat = 
        1     4     5
        1     3     4     5     6
        1     2     3     4     6
        1     2     4     5     6
        1     2     3
        1     2     3     5     6
```

Python:

```
vvern_py = array([[ -6.93864391,   1.79801934,  -7.78610533],
                  [-15.9902125 , -20.80310202,  50.1840397 ],
                  [ 29.501584  , 106.36899584,   5.92137852],
                  [  8.68156407,  -6.58985621,  -0.17410448],
                  [ -0.20266123,   2.12100225,   0.58735065]])

vceln_py = [[],
            [-1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
            [-1, 2, 3],
            [-1, 0, 1],
            [-1, 0, 1, 2, 4],
            [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            [-1, 0, 1, 3, 4]]
```

When you focus on `vceln`, you would notice the values are the same between MATLAB and Python because you can get `vceln_mat` by adding two to `vceln_py`.
However, the line order is different, and I had difficulty converting `vceln_py` to `vceln_mat`.

I thought I could solve this problem by applying `Qhull` options of MATLAB to Python, but I couldn't get the same output. (About options of voronoin: https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoin.html?lang=en#bqurvsm-1)
If anyone can solve this problem, I would really appreciate.

Comment: the order of the lines in the result should not matter, because it depends on what the algorithm is doing under the hood. I would suggest you to somehow sort the output of vceln_*, so that you obtain the same result.

Comment: @giosans The ordering does matter as each line is associated to a specific input point. See my answer for details on this

Comment: Thanks @gehbiszumeis. You have been able to apply what I just mention with "somehow sort the output". :)

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of the lists in `vor.regions` can be arbitrary. However, you can get the information of which region is associated with which entry point via the `vor.point_region` attribute. The [scipy.spatial.Voronoi documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) says

> ```
> point_region: (list of ints, shape (npoints)) Index of the Voronoi region for each input point.
> ```

So you have to order `vor.regions` according to that information in `vor.point_region`

```
# Find point coordinate for each region
sorting = [np.where(vor.point_region==x)[0][0] for x in range(1, len(vor.regions))]
# sort regions along coordinate list `sorting` (exclude first, empty list [])
sorted_regions = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(sorting, vor.regions[1:]))]

sorted_regions = [[-1, 2, 3],
                  [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [-1, 0, 1, 2, 4],
                  [-1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
                  [-1, 0, 1],
                  [-1, 0, 1, 3, 4]]
```

Like this you obtain the ordering of the MATLAB `voronoin` function, which apparently does this sorting already intrinsically.

To get also the same numerical values you can calculate (as you mentioned already do)

```
# PseudoCode 
vceln_py = vceln_mat - 2
```

However, the reason for that seems to be documented neither in [scipy.spatial.Voronoi](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html), [voronoin](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoin.html) nor in the [qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is an empty list member in `vor.regions` and its index is removed from `vor.point_region`, so `len(vor.region) = len(vor.point_region) + 1`. In this case, @gehbiszumeis answer may raise error. I suggest using this line of code:

```
sorted_regions = [vor.regions[reg] for reg in vor.point_region]
```